# Can't open display. Error with IceWM

Tags: linux, x11, window-manager, startx, icewm

I wanted to create **my own** small lightweight distro based on **Debian**. So I have decided to use **IceWM**, **Xorg** and **XDM**. I used these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install icewm xserver-xorg xdm
apt-get update
```

But when I type in `icewm` or `icewm-session` it just says

```
Can't open display: <none>. X must be running and $DISPLAY set.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how you are not supposed to start window managers from the console. Instead, run

```
startx /usr/bin/icewm-session
```

To make your life easier, create `~/.xinitrc` this way

```
cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc
echo icewm-session >> ~/.xinitrc
```

so that you do not need to specify the path to the window manager and simply issue

```
startx
```

Read more in [xinit Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit).